# Can exploding gradient occur in one dataset but not another?

Tags: tensorflow, conv-neural-network

For learning purposes, I have implemented a few popular CNN architectures like GoogLeNet, VGG etc. These were originally designed for ImageNet classification. However since I am doing this for learning purposes, I am training them on MNIST. This way I can get rapid results on my PC.

I am observing a recurring problem of exploding gradients or rather very high values of activation (`about 1e+10`). The papers say nothing about this and the other online implementations do nothing to prevent this. Apparently, I am the only one having this problem.

As a temporary solution I clipped the activations (not gradients) using `tf.clip_by_norm`. This works surprisingly well.

My point is, why are the gradients exploding for me and nobody else? Is it because I am using a different dataset (MNIST)?

Here is [one of my scripts.](https://gist.github.com/Ghost---Shadow/52a4998cc4d5dc0862ccd8e32cfb2305)

Comment: did you try with different learning rates ? what happens if you decrease LR more to 0.0001 ?

Comment: Tried with 1e-5, didnt work. My clipping gets 85-90% accuracy. This doesnt get past 10%.
https://pastebin.com/KC2Uxh2v

Comment: yes, it's typical to get params/architecture tuned for one dataset cause exploding gradients in another

Comment: @YaroslavBulatov Lets say, tomorrow I use ImageNet. Will clipping the activations have any adverse effects? If not, why dont all architectures using ReLU do clipping?

Comment: Yes, clipping can have an adverse effect. Generally the things that make training more stable, also slow down the convergence. The fastest training is achieved by pushing the parameters to the edge of stability.